# Why dynamic bootstrap version 3 date picker is not working?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

am new to the twitter bootstrap version 3 and taken example from [link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example7) .

Here wanted to put n number of date ranges from like n from number of repetitions .

It is working normally.

But when it was used dynamically, it is not working.

Code i have used is

```
     var number_of_repetitions = text;
                         var container = $('#date_list');

if (number_of_repetitions > numItems) {
                             for (var i = numItems + 1; i <= number_of_repetitions; i++)
                             $('<div class="well">'
   +'<div class="form-group">'
     + '<label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Enter Date Range Text ' + i + '</label>'
     +' <div class="col-sm-4">'
         +'<input class="form-control"   id="text_' + i + '" type="text" />'
      +'</div>'
 +' </div>'
   +'<div class="container">'
      +'<div class="col-sm-3"> </div>'
      +'<div class="col-sm-9" style="height:75px;">'
         +'<div class="col-md-6">'
            +'<div class="form-group">'
              +' <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">From</label>'
               +'<div class="input-group date form_date col-md-5" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-link-field="from' + i + '" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">'
                  +'<input class="form-control"  size="14" type="text" value=""  >'
                 + '<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>'
               +'</div>'
               +'<input type="hidden" id="from' + i + '" value="" /><br/>'
            +'</div>'
        + '</div>'
         +'<div class="col-md-6">'
            +'<div class="form-group">'
              + '<label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">To</label>'
               +'<div class="input-group date form_date col-md-5" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-link-field="dtp_input7" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">'
                  +'<input id="acpro_inp1" class="form-control"  size="14" type="text" value=""  >'
                  +'<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>'
               +'</div>'
               +'<input type="hidden" id="dtp_input7" value="" /><br/>'
            +'</div>'
        + '</div>'
      +'</div>'
   +'</div>'
+'</div>').click(function() {

                             }).appendTo(container);
                         }
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding it dinamically, you should call methods to the HTML events to tell Date Picker to work on this elements. If you see the [example (of the link)](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example7) you given, there is a script that contains the following code:

```
$('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: "11/1/13",
    disabledDates: [
        moment("12/25/2013"),
        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
        "11/22/2013 00:53"
     ]
});
```

`$("#datetimepicker7")` is the element on which date time picker will be working.
Returning to your code, after append this HTML (after `.appendTo(container);`) you should call `.datetimepicker()` in the HTML elements you want to work the plugin (I guess elements with class 'form_date'). An example could be: `$(".form_date").datetimepicker();`

If you need to start with a default date, you can add an argument, like in the [link example](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example7), with the object 'defaultDate'. Example: `$(".form_date").datetimepicker({defaultDate: "2/2/14"});`

I hope I've helped :)